# Adding dependecy on module in gradle Java

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a microservice that is Customer and also I have a common module that is called common. I have been trying to use a file that is called ResponseModel from common module in Customer service.

It says that "add dependency on module 'common main'".
Reference is not added even though I click the option.

I am a beginner in Java and using Intellij Idea.

Can anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved by removing **.idea folder** and then rebuilded the project.
Thank you so much, @FloFromYet

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html

So you can add manually, the common dependency in the customer sub-project.
To do this, you need to adapt the build.gradle file of customer:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':common')
}
```

Do not also forgetto reload your project like described here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-projects.html#gradle_refresh_project

Comment: @broche I did this, but it is getting an error. It says that  "A problem occurred evaluating root project 'customer'.
> Project with path ':common' could not be found in root project 'customer'.

Comment: @İsmailDoğan can you share this project on github or on another code repository?

Comment: https://idodevjobs.wordpress.com/2017/02/25/gradle-multi-module-example-type-ii-flat/
Have you a settings.gradle file describing your flat structure?

Comment: hello, I have just published to my github repository. You can check it out. https://github.com/dogaanismail/bank-solution.

Comment: I do not know how I can create this file and build the structure for the file. I have been researching for hours, but I could not do it.

Comment: OK.... I checkout your project and remove the .idea folder because, it is user specific.
And there was no compilation error.
Did you try to reload your project:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-projects.html#gradle_refresh_project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242960/discussion-between-flofromyet-and-smail-dogan).